# Data insert issue

Tags: hive, hdfs, hql

So i had this problem when adding a CSV file to my HQL code and run it on HDFS.
i found that when inserting data it get Nulls in partition parts and some columns gets delete i tried many different ways to insert data but still i gets this weird symbols and lost columns it is like that it cant read the CSV file ,
here is a Pic
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wk42s.png)  and  here is the code`

```
CREATE database covid_db;

use covid_db;


SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions=500;
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=500;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS covid_db.covid_staging 
(
 Country                            STRING,
 Total_Cases                        DOUBLE,
 New_Cases                          DOUBLE,
 Total_Deaths                       DOUBLE,
 New_Deaths                         DOUBLE,
 Total_Recovered                    DOUBLE,
 Active_Cases                       DOUBLE,
 Serious                            DOUBLE,
 Tot_Cases                          DOUBLE,
 Deaths                             DOUBLE,
 Total_Tests                        DOUBLE,
 Tests                              DOUBLE,
 CASES_per_Test                     DOUBLE,
 Death_in_Closed_Cases              STRING,
 Rank_by_Testing_rate               DOUBLE,
 Rank_by_Death_rate                 DOUBLE,
 Rank_by_Cases_rate                 DOUBLE,
 Rank_by_Death_of_Closed_Cases      DOUBLE
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED by ','
STORED as TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/user/cloudera/ds/COVID_HDFS_LZ'
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1", "serialization.null.format" = "''");

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS covid_db.covid_ds_partitioned 
(
 Country                            STRING,
 Total_Cases                        DOUBLE,
 New_Cases                          DOUBLE,
 Total_Deaths                       DOUBLE,
 New_Deaths                         DOUBLE,
 Total_Recovered                    DOUBLE,
 Active_Cases                       DOUBLE,
 Serious                            DOUBLE,
 Tot_Cases                          DOUBLE,
 Deaths                             DOUBLE,
 Total_Tests                        DOUBLE,
 Tests                              DOUBLE,
 CASES_per_Test                     DOUBLE,
 Death_in_Closed_Cases              STRING,
 Rank_by_Testing_rate               DOUBLE,
 Rank_by_Death_rate                 DOUBLE,
 Rank_by_Cases_rate                 DOUBLE,
 Rank_by_Death_of_Closed_Cases      DOUBLE
)
PARTITIONED BY (COUNTRY_NAME STRING)
STORED as TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/user/cloudera/ds/COVID_HDFS_PARTITIONED';

FROM
covid_db.covid_staging
INSERT INTO TABLE covid_db.covid_ds_partitioned PARTITION(COUNTRY_NAME)
SELECT *,Country WHERE Country is not null;


CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE covid_db.covid_final_output 
(
 TOP_DEATH                          STRING,
 TOP_TEST                           STRING
)
PARTITIONED BY (COUNTRY_NAME STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED by ','
STORED as TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/user/cloudera/ds/COVID_FINAL_OUTPUT';
```

`

Answer (score 0):

1st: You are checking file contents, and partition column is not stored in the file, it is stored in the metadata. Also dynamically created partition are directories in the format key=value. So, the last column you see in the file is not the partition column, it is Rank_by_Death_of_Closed_Cases.

2nd: You did not specify delimiter in second table DDL as well as NULL format. The default delimiter is '\001' (Ctrl-A). You can specify delimiter, for example TAB (\t) and desired NULL:

```
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
NULL DEFINED AS ''
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

But  better do not redefine NULL format if you want to be able to distinguish NULLs and empty strings.